# Saving multipe arrays in React state that come from an API

Tags: reactjs, state

So I've been trying to use the Flickr API, and at the moment everything goes well, I have just 1 problem when I try to save the request. So here is what the json returns :

```
{ "photos": { "page": 1, "pages": "1658", "perpage": 40, "total": "66295", 
   "photo": [
     { "id": "47905663711", "owner": "57919329@N02", "secret": "3beafe6fc0", "server": 0, "farm": 0, "title": "Aquarius Marine Crit-2.mp4", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "47101365784", "owner": "76692047@N00", "secret": "68850da8e0", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "Wilmington Grand Prix", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40916414493", "owner": "33910095@N03", "secret": "5da9c47e6d", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "Lincoln Grand Prix", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32916014317", "owner": "150917132@N04", "secret": "51a7302355", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "cycling for a cause", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46909807285", "owner": "67394469@N06", "secret": "350c4240e0", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "1970 GIRO Back on my bike", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211825", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "9d99a4eb48", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211685", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "b81f3814b4", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844215023", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "6a6d46a5c1", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844214893", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "da9da11591", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866966757", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "c84d43aa47", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211545", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "34ba65d840", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211495", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "21cf7dc287", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866966587", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "c4bc889f95", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211395", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "33f821dc03", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844214633", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "9372aa0607", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211365", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "399b88aeac", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211265", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "a0f5112174", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211215", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "46280f4a53", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844214513", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "fb3db26938", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866966307", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "6d4873ae81", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866966147", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "4751f22511", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211165", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "38fae0b9c4", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844214393", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "6bc7116178", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894211055", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "c2fea68ca3", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866966077", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "432e38eb97", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965877", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "a06989656f", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965977", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "bb183969df", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894210865", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "c6949ebc40", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965797", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "f1dd19e962", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "46894210785", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "cdbb831ba2", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965737", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "8cfdb4a542", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965617", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "fbafea96b0", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844213863", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "a428785507", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965577", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "d81980aa8a", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965447", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "1e71293309", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844213753", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "ae3b2494a2", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965297", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "92724f458e", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844213783", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "fc8588f1c6", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "32866965197", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "ec291f9400", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
     { "id": "40844213643", "owner": "62169608@N02", "secret": "1ef1ba2ced", "server": "65535", "farm": 66, "title": "8bar crit 2019 Berlin - fixed gear race", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 }
   ] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

I've handled this so I get a java array for each of the pictures, but now how do I save this in my state, I've already tried this :

```
fetch(url)
            .then(res => {
                return res.json()
            })
            .then(jsonRes => {
                const photoList = jsonRes.photos.photo
                photoList.forEach(pic => {
                    this.setState({
                        photos: pic
                    })
                    console.log(pic.id, pic.server, pic.farm, pic.secret)
                })
            })
```

But of course it will only save the last one. So how do I save all these in a state?

Comment: You are updating state's photos variable with a single pic object everytime, so only last one is saved in photos. Instead of iterating through array, just update state's photos with photoList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
fetch(url)
        .then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
        .then(jsonRes => {
            this.setState({
                photos: jsonRes.photos.photo
            })
        })
```